# AngularJS - What is the best way to detect undefined null or empty value at the same time?

Tags: angularjs

Sometimes I need to check a value for three conditions at the same time, null, undefined or "". Due that I haven´t found any method to do this, I coded my own and it works.

```
$scope.isNullOrEmptyOrUndefined = function (value) {
    if (value === "" || value === null || typeof value === "undefined") {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Just wanted to know if there is a better way to accomplish the same thing.

Thanks so much in advance,

Guillermo

Comment: What if it is false or NaN ? Do you have a chance that value can be them as well? if so just do `return !value`. ALso you can also do `value == null` that will cover undefined as well.

Comment: `angular.isDefined()` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined

Comment: @gearsdigital, why don't you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update

As mentioned in the comments it's better to use `return !value`.

```
$scope.isValid = function(value) {
    return !value
}
```

#### Old and incomplete Answer

A proper way is simply to use [`angular.isDefined()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined)

Comment: `function isDefined(value){return typeof value !== 'undefined';}
` This is the implementation of the function.

Comment: This only checks for undefined, not empty string or null.  `return !value` is the correct answer.

Comment: If the function isValid is supposed to return true if the parameter is not undefined or empty, then it should return !!value. Now it returns true for undefined and empty parameters.

Answer (score 14):

How about this?  Since you seem to be returning true in those null/undefined cases:

```
$scope.isNullOrEmptyOrUndefined = function (value) {
    return !value;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1feLd9yn/3/

Note that an empty array and empty object will also return false as they are truthy values.  If you want the true/false return to be flip-flopped, then omit the ! before value.

Comment: Why just 3 negations when you can use 5 or 7?

Comment: True, it's a double negation.

Comment: Interesting.  I was trying to avoid the function actually returning 'value' and instead type-coercing the value to its boolean representation.  Looks like return !value does that.  Updated my answer

Comment: Of course it does, after the first negation, you're in the boolean world, and every additional pair of negations is just a waste because it returns the same thing. A single pair of negations is a shortcut for typecasting variables into boolean, and that's fine (`!!var`).

Comment: @Shomz `null == !!null` //false

Comment: @Ofiris Yes, null is not a boolean, so `anything == !!anything` will return false unless `anything` is true... Anyway: `!null == !!(!null)` //true. See his original answer to see what were the comments about.

Comment: The problem with this answer occurs when value is 0 (Number). Since 0 is falsey, the function will return true even though we don't want it to. Nice try  at being succinct though.

Comment: @NikoBellic You are correct. What I have observed is that when I enter 0 as a value and check for its validity against check for empty strin `''`, it fails. I have to check it against `undefined` in order for it to work.

Comment: I was always taught that if my function names had or in them, they were doing too much!

Answer (score 1):

```
**AngularJS - What is the best way to detect undefined null or empty value at the same time?**
```

You can define a function or you can use inline command.

```
$scope.isNullOrUndefined = function(value){
   return (!value) && (value === null)
}

or 

var temp = null;
(temp) ? 'I am not null' : 'yes I am null or undefined';
"yes I am null or undefined"

var temp = undefined
(temp) ? 'I am not null' : 'yes I am null or undefined';
"yes I am null or undefined"

temp = '123123Rec'
(temp) ? 'I am not null' : 'yes I am null or undefined';
"I am not null"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your code and put in a description so people can understand what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code, it's working perfect in my angular js application.

```
function isValid(value) {
            return typeof value !== 'undefined';
        };
```